# Templating AJAX return data

Tags: php, html, ajax, templates, mustache

I am receiving data  from php in the form on an obj, and am sending it through a mustache template to make a table.

My question is how can i control the row breaks for my data, I wish to insert a `<tr`> for every 3 `<td>` is this possible without the help of Javascript?

### Data coming from PHP:

```
    {"Form":[
{"Label":"Name","Info":"megan fox"},
{"Label":"Phone","Info":"(111) 222-3333"},
{"Label":"Name","Info":"sfsdfsdf"},
{"Label":"Zip","Info":"dsfsdfs"},
{"Label":"State","Info":"sdfsf"},
{"Label":"City","Info":"4fsfsf"},
{"Label":"Address","Info":"dfsodufsf"},
{"Label":"Phone #","Info":"(111) 222-3333"},
{"Label":"Zip","Info":"34545345"},
{"Label":"State","Info":"sdfsf"},
{"Label":"City","Info":"sdfosdffd"},
{"Label":"Address","Info":"sdfsfssf"}
    ]}
```

### Mustache template

```
<table>
{{#Form}}
<tr>
<td><span class="label">{{Label}}</span>
<span class="Information">{{Info}}</span> 
</td>
</tr>
{{/Form}}
</table>
```

### Result

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><span class="label">Name</span> 
<span class="Information">megan fox</span> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="label">Phone</span> 
<span class="Information">(434) 434-543</span> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="label">Name</span> 
<span class="Information">sfsdfsdf</span> </td>
</tr>
   ..
</tbody>
</table>
```

### What I want: 3 TD in 1 TR.

```
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td><span class="label">Name</span> 
<span class="Information">megan fox</span> </td>
<td><span class="label">Phone</span> 
<span class="Information">(111) 222-3333</span> </td>
<td><span class="label">Name</span> 
<span class="Information">sfsdfsdf</span> </td>
</tr>
...
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the manual here http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html is says that

> When the value is a non-empty list, the text in the block will be
>   displayed once for each item in the list. The context of the block
>   will be set to the current item for each iteration. In this way we can
>   loop over collections.

I think that if you can change the output from the server, this may offer the simplest solution. Can you get the output to look like this?

```
{
    "Form": {
        "Items": [
            {"Label": "Name", "Info": "megan fox"},
            {"Label": "Phone", "Info": "(111) 222-3333"},
            {"Label": "Name", "Info": "sfsdfsdf"},
            {"Label": "Zip", "Info": "dsfsdfs"},
            {"Label": "State", "Info": "sdfsf"},
            {"Label": "City", "Info": "4fsfsf"},
            {"Label": "Address", "Info": "dfsodufsf"},
            {"Label": "Phone #", "Info": "(111) 222-3333"},
            {"Label": "Zip", "Info": "34545345"},
            {"Label": "State", "Info": "sdfsf"},
            {"Label": "City", "Info": "sdfosdffd"},
            {"Label": "Address", "Info": "sdfsfssf"}
        ]
    }
}
```

If so, you can then get your template to iterate over the Items, you will then need to change your template to this;

```
<table>
{{#Form}}
<tr>
{{#Items}}
<td><span class="label">{{Label}}</span>
<span class="Information">{{Info}}</span> 
</td>
{{/Items}}
</tr>
{{/Form}}
</table>
```